# Symfony2 and zclip: apostrophe turn into & # 0 3 9 ;

Tags: symfony, zclip

I'm using jquery.zclip and Symfony2 framework to copy text to the client's clipboard. It works fine but for the fact that the apostrophe's transform into & # 0 3 9 ; (without the spaces)

The problem apparently comes from Twig templating engine that transforms my apostrophes into their html entities.

I would like to find a solution to prevent Twig doing this. Or maybe turn them back to apostrophes before calling zclip?

How would you do that?

Here is my jquery/twig code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img#copy-description').zclip({
            path:"{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf') }}",
            copy:"{{ introLine1 }}{{ introLine2 }}{{ introLine3 }}{{ introLine4 }}{{ introLine5 }}",
            afterCopy:function(){
                alert('The poem has been copied to the clipboard.');
            },
        });
    });

</script>
```

This code then becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img#copy-description').zclip({
    path:"/yourownpoet/web/bundles/yopyourownpoet/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy:"Franz, hope Boston treats you wellDaddy, I have a story to tellIf you do not mindI&#039;ll promise it&#039;s kindLike the sweet ringing of a bell",
    afterCopy:function(){
    alert('The poem has been copied to the clipboard.');
    },
});
```

EDIT: I tried something more which doesn't work neither:

```
    function escape(string)
    {
        return string.replace("&#039;", "'");
    }

        $('img#copy-description').zclip({
            path:"{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf') }}",
            copy: escape("{{ introLine1 }}")+"\n"+escape("{{ introLine2 }}")+"\n"+escape("{{ introLine3 }}")+"\n"+escape("{{ introLine4 }}")+"\n"+escape("{{ introLine5 }}"),
            afterCopy:function(){
                alert('The poem has been copied to the clipboard.');
            },
        });
```

But I still get the code instead of apostrophe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter if you consider your variable safe:

```
{{ var|raw }}
```

You can also change the [autoescaping strategy](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#escaper-extension) to javascript (probably better option):

```
{% autoescape true js %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img#copy-description').zclip({
            path:"{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf') }}",
            copy:"{{ introLine1 }}{{ introLine2 }}{{ introLine3 }}{{ introLine4 }}{{ introLine5 }}",
            afterCopy:function(){
                alert('The poem has been copied to the clipboard.');
            },
        });
    });
</script>
{% endautoescape %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#escaper-extension

Comment: I know that my variable is safe so I'm just using the raw filter. Thanks a lot I totally forgot about this one...

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
string_name = '{{ string_name|e('js')|raw }}';
```