# Apostrophe converted into & # 039 ; in twig

Tags: html, string, symfony, twig, special-characters

This question has been asked before here:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631183/symfony2-and-zclip-apostrophe-turn-into-0-3-9)

**But it doesn't solve my problem.**

After I got data from database with apostrophe, I'm putting it inside a text input using

```
c_name='{{company_name}}';
$("#company_name").val(c_name);
```

It's giving result like

> some Hatchery & Shrimp & #039;s Culture ltd.

So I applied the solution of that question like

```
c_name='{{company_name|raw}}';
$("#company_name").val(c_name);
```

It's giving me an error like

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement 
c_name='some Hatchery & Shrimp's Culture ltd.';
```

Showing error just after the Shrimp' and before s.
Obviously string ended before it actually ends and expecting a ;

So I tried again with

```
c_name={{company_name|raw}};

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
c_name=some Hatchery & Shrimp's Culture ltd.;
```

Now it's showing error just after the first white space,in this case before 'H'

**My question is how can I handle apostrophe in twig?** '|raw' is causing problem for me.

Comment: Have you tried to replace apostrophe with double-quotes in your js code? Seems like it could help.

Comment: Do you mean this c_name="{{company_name|raw}}"; ? or the replace function? Both of them no use. First one will not work for if dynamic string contains any double-quote and 2nd one will not work if there is more than one apostrophe like 2/3 apostrophes in the string. @DarmenAmanbayev

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
c_name = '{{ company_name|e('js')|raw }}';
```

Since you're in a Javascript context, you need to escape for Javascript (and then add `raw` to avoid additional automatic escaping for HTML).

Comment: You don't need the raw filter, it won't be escaped again so there's nothing to avoid. It's also worth mentioning that the `e` is a short alias to the `escape` filter.

Comment: @Maerlyn The documentation says differently: *When using automatic escaping, Twig tries to not double-escape a variable __when the automatic escaping strategy is the same as the one applied by the escape__ filter* (emphasis added) - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html

Comment: I've never had problems about this, but apparently I can expect them. Thank you for the info!